# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null PHP 7.4

Tags: php, magento2.4.2, php-7.4

I am having a custom module for magento 2.4.2 but with php 7.4 I am having this issue:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /public_html/app/code/mymodule/Helper/Data.php on line 242

when trying to save a product in my admin.

My code in this line is:

```
if (!is_array($section['fields'])) continue;
```

And the whole //check is:

```
$sectionOrder = -1;
            foreach($sections as $key => $section) {
                $sectionOrder++;
                if (!is_array($section['fields'])) continue;
                if (isset($section['template_id']) && !in_array((int) $section['template_id'], $templateIds)) {
                    unset($sections[$key]);
                    $sectionOrder--;
                    continue;
                }
                $sections[$key]['order'] = $sectionOrder;
                foreach($section['fields'] as $key2 => $_field) {
                    if (!is_array($_field)) continue;
                    $sections[$key]['fields'][$key2]['section_order'] = $sectionOrder;
                }
            }
```

With php 7.3 it works but with 7.4 I have problem.

Any help please how I can write this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the source of the error comes from `$section` not being an `array` sometimes, but it wouldn't hurt to also account for array keys on `$section` not being set when it is an `array`.

PHP's **Null Coalescing Operator** is useful here for accounting for the non-existing array key.

**Example of changed line:**

This covers the case when `fields` is not set or `null`. The `??` operator will return the left operand if it is set and is not null, otherwise it will return the right operand of `false` which is definitely not an array:

```
if (!is_array($section['fields'] ?? false)) continue;
```

This will cover the case where `$section` itself is `null` and not an `array`:

```
if (!is_array($section) || !is_array($section['fields'] ?? false)) continue;
```

**Example Use of Null Coalescing Operator**

```
<?php

$foo = [
    'bar' => 'Some Value'
];

// The key 'baz' does not exist
$baz = $foo['baz'] ?? 'nothing';

// The array offset error will be prevented.
// Output will be: 'nothing'
echo $baz;
```

**Example Directly From php.net**

Referenced from: [PHP 7.0 new features](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

Comment: Could you give a example?

Comment: Updated answer to point out the line of code that should change. Or do you want to see examples of using the null coalescing operator?

Comment: Your answer worked just fine!! Thank you!

Comment: It's still valuable knowing about the Null Coalescing Operator, but after looking at your error again, I wonder if it's actually `$section` that is sometimes null. It wouldn't hurt to check that as well as it may be the original source of the error.

Comment: What you mean by that please?

Comment: I have updated answer again. See example changes to your line

Comment: Second update give new error at line below: `foreach($section['fields'] as $key2 => $_field) {`

Comment: Apologize. I might have updated since last time you looked at it. Look at the second example again and let me know if that causes an error. I changed it to check if `$section` itself is an array.

Comment: Yes. Now it is working again! All good